# Does function constructor support computed properties with `this`?

Tags: javascript

Trying to test something like ≈

```
> function Computed(name, prop) {
... [this.prop]: name
... };
...    // but this doesn't work.
```

Is there a way to do it properly?

Comment: What is `this` referencing at code at Question? What is expected result of `[this.prop]: name`?

Comment: @guest271314, I just wanted to mark this word as a code-relevant part.

Comment: Note, if `this` is `window` `"name"` could be a property of `window`, a string.

Comment: Are you trying to set two values at the assignment, `"prop"` of `this` to `this.prop` or `prop`, and value to `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed properties `{ [x]: y }` are part of the object literal syntax, but constructors are just functions; you can make use of the usual bracket notation to refer to properties with dynamic names in statements inside them.

```
function Computed(name, prop) {
    this[name] = prop;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Computed properties work only inside class bodies or object literals, not in functions (just like normal property definitions don't). But you don't need them there anyway: you can just use bracket syntax to create properties on the instance:

```
function Computed(name, prop) {
    this[prop] = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set property at `this` using computed property you can use `Object.assign()` with first with `this` passed as first parameter

```
function Computed(name, prop) {
  // this.prop = "abc";
  Object.assign(this, {[this.prop]:name});  
};
```

Comment: Iteresting. However, it's just an intellectual exercise, right? Something to consider just for example? Is there a real-life situation to use this, not the answers by @Bergi and Ryan?

Comment: The Answer addresses the use of the syntax at Question. You can select either Answer to achieve same result. What is the purpose of the code at Question if not to determine if the specific syntax can be used to set a property of an object?